# Definition of topological space & open sets

Tags: general-topology, definition

I am just getting into topology, and I have a doubt regarding open sets.

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Given an open set of $X$, $A$, and subset of $X$, $B$ such that

$$A\cap B \in \mathcal{T}$$
$$A\cup B \in \mathcal{T}$$

Can I conclude that $B$ is also an open set? That is, if I have an arbitrary set of $X$ whose intersection and union with an open set are themselves open sets, does this imply the arbitrary set is also open?

Comment: How about this example where $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$ and $A\cup B\ne X$:  $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\mathcal T=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It does not imply that the set is open. For instance:

Let $X= \left\lbrace a, b, c\right\rbrace$ and consider the topological space $(X, \tau)$ where $\tau=\left\lbrace\varnothing, X, \left\lbrace a \right\rbrace\right\rbrace$.

Let $A=\left\lbrace a \right\rbrace$, let $B=\left\lbrace b, c \right\rbrace$.

Then,

$A \cup B= X \ \in \ \tau $,

$A \cap B= \varnothing \ \in \ \tau$.

However $B \ \notin \ \tau$.

Comment: I would recommend denoting the empty set as $\emptyset$ rather than $\phi$.

Comment: You can use either `\emptyset` $\emptyset$ or `\varnothing` $\varnothing$.

Comment: True that! Thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 12):

No. Consider the usual topology on $X=\mathbb R$ with $A=(-\infty,0)$ and $B=[0,\infty)$.

$A\cap B=\emptyset\in\mathcal T$, $ A\cup B=X\in\mathcal T$, $A\in\mathcal T$, and $B\not\in\mathcal T$.